# let $h$ be an affine function and $g$ a convex function. Then $C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n| h(x)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad g(x)\leq0\}$ is a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming

Let $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an affine function and $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a convex function.

Then $C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n| h(x)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad g(x)\leq0\}$ is a convex set.

My try:
I want to show that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $(1-t)a+tb\in C$

By definition of the set $C$ we know that $h(x)=a^tx+b=0$ and that for $t\in[0,1]$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $g(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tg(x)+(1-t)g(y)\leq 0 $

I'm not sure on what to do next. Maybe adding both equation, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Can you show that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid g(x)\leq0\}$ is a convex set? Do you realize that an affine function is convex? Do you know that the intersection of convex sets is again convex?

Comment: Did you mean both to be $h$ or was one supposed to be $g$?

Comment: The intersection of any number of convex sets is convex. A function $h$ is affine **iff** both $h$ and $-h$ are convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be an affine function and let $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Then

$h(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)=a^t(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)+b=t(a^tx_1+b)+(1-t)(a^tx_2+b)= \\=th(x_1)+(1-t)h(x_2),$

$x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \ t \in [0,1]$. Hence $h$ is a convex function. Conclude that $\{x \in \mathbb{R^n}: h(x)=0\}$ is a convex set. Since $g$ is a convex function,

$g(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \leq tg(x_1)+(1-t)g(x_2) \leq 0$,

$x_1,x_2 \in \{x \in \mathbb{R^n}: g(x) \leq 0\}, \ t \in [0,1]$.

Thus $\{x \in \mathbb{R^n}: g(x) \leq 0\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R^n}: h(x)=0\}=\{x \in \mathbb{R^n}: g(x) \leq 0 \ \wedge\ \ h(x)=0 \}$ is a convex set.